# Android Studio - Long Click On A Button

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have an `Button` and when I click it it plays a Sound. When I hold the `Button` for a second, I want that a `menu` will open where I can select where the sound **should be shared (whatsapp...)**.

Does anybody know how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
        String audioFilePath    = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/yourfolder/youraudiofile.ogg";
        Uri uri                 = Uri.parse(audioFilePath);
        Intent share            = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("audio/*");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Audio File"));
```

Comment: ok but now when I hold the button nothing happens, but when the sound is finished playing then the share menu opens

Comment: See the first answer here. Put this code inside that longclick function.

Comment: "button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() { " what have I put at "button" ? because the button is button1

Comment: use button1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

Answer (score 2):

You can use following listener and put your code inside it.

```
button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First you implement a Long pressed click listener like this

```
       button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    String audioFilePath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/pathoffile.ogg";
    Uri uri= Uri.parse(audioFilePath);
    Intent share= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("audio/*");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share The Audio")); 
            return true;
        }
    });
```

When this function is run It will open all the sharing applications in your mobile will open like whatsapp, bluetooth,shareit, zapya etc etc